# Read from a file until a space is found

Tags: c, file, operating-system, posix, system-calls

I'm new to C programming, so I wonder if it's possible to read from a certain file using the system call `read()` until a space is found.

Example:

A file contains a number and a process PID (59 5542). I want to read first the number, saving it into a variable and then do the same thing with the PID.

Thanks in advance.

P.S: since this is an exercise for my Operating Systems class, I have to use `read()`.

Comment: Byte by byte, until space is found.

Comment: Consider not insisting on using `read()`. What are your reasons to do so?

Comment: @Yunnosch because this is an exercise for my Operating Systems class, so I have to use `read()`.

Comment: I see. I recommend to explain that in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend first reading the number and the PID with one `read()` call into a sufficiently large buffer, then saving both into variables, e. g.:

```
    char buf[20] = { 0 }, *end;
    read(fd, buf, sizeof buf - 1);
    int num, PID;
    num = strtol(buf, &end, 0);
    PID = strtol(end, NULL, 0);
```